# difference between double and double& in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, types, reference

I have the following function to calculate the mean of a double[] in c++:

```cpp
double& Vector::mean() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += *(arr + i);
    }
    double m = sum / size;
    return m;
}
```

this compiles and runs, but this doesn't:

```cpp
double& Vector::mean() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += *(arr + i);
    }
    return (sum / size);
}
```

With the following error:

```
Non-const lvalue reference to type 'double' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'double'
```

This is implemented in a class where `arr` is of type `double*`.

What is the difference between simply returning `sum / size` and returning a variable `double m = sum / size`? I have a vague idea that the reason has something to do with the difference between types `double` and `double&` but, but wouldn't returning `m` be the same as returning a calculated double value? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Even though the first one seems to work, it is wrong too. Remove the &.

Comment: Yes never return references to local variables, the values the reference "points" to will be gone after the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `double&` indicates that you are returning by reference.  This means that rather than directly returning a value, the function returns a memory location where the value is stored, which is immediately dereferenced and converted to a value in the calling code in most cases.  Since `sum/size` is an expression and not a variable, an address cannot be identified and the compiler throws an error.  However, `m` is a variable and has an address that can be returned.  However, in this case `m` falls out of scope immediately when the member function exits, so this also should not be done.  In this case it would probably be more appropriate to return`double`, which returns a value directly to the calling code.